# Why is $b/\|w\|$ the offset of the hyperplane to the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

There is one detail about hyperplanes I just cant prove myself (it's so simple a direct proof should work)...

Claim:

Given a hyperplane with (non normalized) normal vector $w$,
$$ w\cdot x - b =0 , b\in\mathbb{R}, x,w\in\mathbb{R}^n. $$
Then the offset from the hyperplane to the origin in the direction of $w$ is given by $b/\|w\|$.

Proof:

(Thank you AndreaS.)

As it's the offset of the hyperplane to the origin, we should be able to shift all $x$ in the hyperplane by $\frac{b}{\|w\|}$ units along the unit vector $\color{red}{\frac{w}{\|w\|}}$, and have the origin $0$ satisfy the resulting equality. Indeed, the shifted hyperplane becomes
$$ w \cdot \left(x+\frac{b}{\|w\|} \color{red}{\frac{w}{\|w\|}}\right) -b =0 $$
$$ w \cdot x + \frac{b( w \cdot w)}{\|w\|^2} -b=0$$
$$ w \cdot x=0$$
We see that $x=0$ satisfies this equality as desired

Comment: I think that in the thesis of the claim the "offset" should be $w\frac{b}{||w||^2}$. I used the word offset marked because I'm not familiar with how it is defined and could not find a definition after a rapid Google search.

Comment: @AndreaS.  I got it, youre right! Editting now

Comment: @AndreaS.  Also the word "offset" I understand as the scalar repesenting the distance between the origin and its orthogonal projection onto the hyperplane